# How to use IME(Input Method Editor) with pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

my platform: ubuntu14.04

python 3.4.0

I moved my project from `pyqt4` to `pyqt5` and fond that I could not enable my IME in my program powered by `pyqt5`...

Since there is no error raised, I could not focus to where the problem is.

This problem is quite like "enable IME in Sublime on Linux".

Anyone meet the same problem or have already fixed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by `fcitx` not `QT5`.

Install `libfcitx-qt5` and it will fix the problem.